# Creating Rest API without views using cakePHP 3.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.4, cakephp-3.3

I'm trying to create Rest API without view and planning to use these api's in angular 2 application. does have any idea about it?

Comment: Start reading the manual? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html

Answer (score 1):

Cake makes this incredibly easy. A few things I have learned building without views.

**Set the _serialize variable**

```
$data = ['cheeses' => ['gouda', 'pepper jack', 'cheddar']];
$this->set('responseData', $data);
$this->set('_serialize', 'responseData');
```

**Throw bad request exceptions and other network related exceptions**

Cake will render nice json views for you.

**Set your accept header when issuing and ajax request to be application/json**

**You can use cake prefixes for api versions**

**Look at [Stateless Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems) for your api**

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppController.php`, with these parameters, all of your controllers will be render in json

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event)
{
     $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
     $this->response->type('application/json');
     $this->set('_serialize', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP will render json easily.

In your Controller,look like something.

```
protected   $responseBody   =   [];

public function beforeRender(Event $event){

    foreach($this->responseBody as $responseKey=>$response){

       $this->set($responseKey, $response);
    }
    $this->set('_serialize', array_keys($this->responseBody));
}

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
}

public function index(){

    $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);  // Method like post,get..

    $this->responseBody["statusCode"]       =   200;

    $this->responseBody["statusDescription"]        =   ''; //You send any text in json.

    $this->responseBody["data"]  =  []; // All data that you can send.
```

}

For further informations , You can see CakePHP Cookbook REST API to click [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html)